# Syntax error cannot import React and React-Dom

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to import React and React-Dom, I'm totally new to react and would appreciate if you could help me. SyntaxError: C:/Users/Genti/Anaconda3/envs/MMS/geodjango/MMS/static/js/index.js: Unexpected token (1:18)

```
> 1 | import React from react;
    |                   ^
  2 | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 |
  4 | function Hello(props) {
```

this is my code:

```
import React from react;
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Hello(props) {
    return <h1> Hey, {props.name} </h1>
}

const element = <Hello name="Gent" />;

ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('react')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple quotes

```
import React from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass react in a string:

```
import React from 'react';
```

The import asks for string path to find in the `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from react; -> import React from 'react';
```

You need to have it as string

Answer (score 0):

You have two imports in your code

```
import React from react;
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

but i the first import you have missed the simple quotes, you can understand it from the error itself it was expecting single quote(') at line 1 and position 18, but it received r as in react, so these is not expected, try to look at the error, you will understand.

so the correct imports will be

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```